# Unity migrates to URP cause some pixel shaders to become transparent

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I'm migrating to URP from the built-in pipeline, and my shader seems to be broken: [multiple cascade terrain mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmaQX.jpg). There are multiple meshes(on different game objects) corresponding to different LOD of the terrain in my scene, and they all share the same shader (but different material parameters).

I'm testing using the simplest fragment shader:

```
float4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                return float4(0.3, 0, 0, 1);
                // original code...
            }
```

The wireframes indicate the vertex shader works well, but I don't know why the pixel shader is not working (mesh becomes transparent except for the "LOD0" mesh)

I tried to use the simplest frag shader, and I'd expect all of the meshes to have a red color.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is probably not shader related, if your shader does not have          Tags { "RenderType"="Transparency" }. It could be that your dimensions are a little bit hight and unity culls those tiles. Try to change the camera clipping plane to more than 1000. Check also if Occlusion culling is enabled somehow.